# Get Value from Combo Cox (view) and send to controller without loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

How I can take value from view's code igniter to controller without loading page..
 I have 2 class in controller, `index` and `create_data`.
I need to print `$test` dinamically
How can I make my code work?

> View

```
<?php echo form_open("example/create_data", "class='form-horizontal' row-border")?>

<select name="example" onchange()="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Tambah</button>
<?php form_close()?>
```

> Controller

```
function index(){
    $data['combo'] = comboData();
    $test = $this->input->post();
    $data['test'] = $test;
    echo $test;
    if ($test==1) { 
        doSomething(); 
    } else{ 
        doNothing(); 
    }
    $this->template->display('example/index',$data);
}
```

Comment: Calling "this.form.submit()" on value change will submit the form, and reload. You need to write some javascript (ajax) to send the value without any reload.

Answer (score 0):

|| view

```
<?php echo form_open("example/create_data", "class='form-horizontal' row-border")?>

<select name="example" onchange="change_option()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="your_second_dropdown_id_name">
    <option value="0">no data</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Tambah</button>
<?php form_close()?>
```

||javascript/jquery

```
var category_id =  $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: category_id,
        url: "<?= base_url() ?>learning/dependent_dropdown",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                var opt = $('<option />'); 
                opt.val(data.id_type);
                opt.text(data.name);
                $('#your_second_dropdown_id_name').append(opt);
            });
        }
    });
```